# KStream.through() not creating intermediate topic, and impacting other processor nodes in topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying out the sample KafkaStreams code from Chapter 4 from the book - **Kafka Streams in Action**.  I pretty much copied the code in github - https://github.com/bbejeck/kafka-streams-in-action/blob/master/src/main/java/bbejeck/chapter_4/ZMartKafkaStreamsAddStateApp.java  This is an example using StateStore.  When I run the code as is, no data is flowing through the topology.  I verified that mock data is being generated, as I can see the offset in the input topic - **transactions** go up.  However, nothing in the output topics, and nothing is printed to console.

However, when I comment line 81-88 (https://github.com/bbejeck/kafka-streams-in-action/blob/master/src/main/java/bbejeck/chapter_4/ZMartKafkaStreamsAddStateApp.java#L81-L88), basically avoid creating the "through()" processor node, the code works.  I see data being generated to the "patterns" topics, and output generate in console.

I am using Kafka broker and client version 2.4.  Would appreciate any help or pointers to debug the issue.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well documented, that you need to create intermediate topic that you use via `through()` manually and upfront before you start your application. Intermediate topics, similar to input and output topics are not managed by Kafka Streams, but it's the users responsibility to manage them.

Cf: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html

Btw: there is work in progress to add a new `repartition()` operator that allows you to repartition via a topic that will be managed by Kafka Streams (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-221%3A+Enhance+DSL+with+Connecting+Topic+Creation+and+Repartition+Hint)

Comment: Thank you, I missed that part in the doc, new to Kafka Streams.

Comment: Can you please tell me why I need to manually create the topic, after all it is an intermediate topic.  I assumed users don't have to create intermediate topics.

Comment: Even if it is an intermediate topic, it is a user topic and not an internal topic. The new `repartition()` operator closes this gap to allow you to have internal intermediate topics.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, why is output topic created automatically, but intermediate - not. I'm using confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:6.0.0 locally with KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"

Comment: If you enable auto topic creation, intermediate topics will be created automatically, too. The answer to the question refers to the recommended setting to disable auto topic creation. For this case, only internal topic are create by KafkaStreams (note, this is an explicit "create topic" request issued by KafkaStreams, it's not broker side topic auto creation).